# I have a string. I want to separate by "/". And print only " item_images " part in react js. please help me how can i do it

Tags: split

I have a string. I want to separate by "/". And print only " item_images " part in react js. please help me how can i do it. ( stagingRelotechApi/public/uploads/item_images/6075_1627302914_MyPCS.jpeg )

Answer (score 0):

You should search more, if you had searched, you could have found the answer, anyway here is the answer.

```js
const a="stagingRelotechApi/public/uploads/item_images/6075_1627302914_MyPCS.jpeg";
const b=a.split('/');
console.log(b[3])
```